# Is there a RAW (canon) image viewer or gallery hack for android?

Tags: images, photos, gallery

I have a samsung galaxy and it has a brilliant screen. I would love to use it to review photos taken on a DSLR while out and about but I haven't managed to find any way to view RAW images in android. My camera is a canon so I guess it would need to have specific support for cacnon's raw format.

Are there any photographers here that can recommend some apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching the Market, I found [RawDroid Demo](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.anthonymandra.rawdroid&feature=search_result). It says it'll open raw files from DSLRs including Canon. I haven't tried it and it doesn't seem to have many downloads, so I'm not sure if it will work.

Comment: Cool it was added to the market yesterday! :-)

Comment: Just for completion, at the point of writing RawDroid is basically a batch converter from raw to jpg. You can then view the jpgs in the usual way. It's a very first release however and I'm sure the app will be updated to have more functionality in future